# Non-greedy matching with grep script

Tags: linux, shell, scripting, grep

I have a string AD/CF/ES/DD/ that i want to grep for but there
are other strings like AD/CF/ES/DD/FG/DD which i'm also matching which i do not want. I only want to match the 4 parts. I've tried something like this but it's matching all levels.

grep -P '[A-Z][A-Z]/[A-Z][A-Z]/[A-Z][A-Z]/[A-Z][A-Z]?'

suggestions please.
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Go the easy way:

```
grep -F AD/CF/ES/DD/ | grep -vF AD/CF/ES/DD/FG/DD
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `grep -P` command:

```
grep -P '\b([A-Z]{2}/){4}\W' file
```